I have nominated "guns" as a synonym of "firearms"
EDIT: Thanks for your votes! The synonym was approved.

I have nominated guns (31 questions) to be a synonym of firearms (162 questions). You can vote for or against here. This is postedin Meta because Stack Exchange does not have a review queue for proposed synonyms.

Hmmm, Barbara W. Tuchman's The Guns of August is definitely not about the firearms of August... And a 40-gun frigate is much more impressive than a 40-firearm frigate. (There were literally hundreds of firearms aboard a 40-gun frigate.) The point being that guns might be man-portable firearms, but in a naval, historical, or fantasy context they are usually cannon. P.S. I cannot vote, or maybe the user interface is beyond my understanding.

@AlexP -- You likely haven't answered enough questions with the relevant tag. There are minimum requirements for voting. I can't vote either. Also, Guns of August should be tagged "novel" or "book" and frigates should be tagged "ships".

"What is the difference between a gun and a firearm?
To get more specific, “gun” is an umbrella term for anything that shoots a projectile, including the massive howitzers that fire artillery shells 20 miles. But a “firearm” is a rifle, pistol or any other kind of smaller, handheld gun." - There's no sailors here getting pissed off that we're use the wrong terms, so w\e I guess. (@AlexP cannon is a countable noun ;)

"A synonym should be defined when there are multiple ways to describe a concept and when typing one of them wouldn't offer an auto-complete to the other : meteorology -> weather... cartography -> map-making, or ai -> artificial-intelligence." ... firearm = gun, but gun does not equal firearm. All squares are rectangles.... IMO you should leave the tags alone.

@Mazura: The word cannon may be countable, or it may be a collective noun. At least that's what dictionaries say. Native speakers are allowed to use the language as they see fit, but we foreigners have to go by the book.

@AlexP While you're technically correct, the [tag:guns] tag hasn't been used that way at all. Worse, out of any 100 users on this site there might, maybe, be one who understands "guns" in the context you're suggesting. In the long run, it should be a synonym because that's the way people are using and I can't actually believe the Stack will see it used more than five times for (e.g.) naval armaments.

@Mazura As I just suggested to AlexP, you're correct! And it's irrelevant because nobody is using the term that way. A quick review of the questions tagged with [tag:guns] doesn't show a single one of them refering to the objects you're describing. And since the average user doesn't read tag wikis, defining [tag:gun] to reflect your comments and then removing it from all of the questions will leave the tag with zero questions untill it's filled again with [tag:firearms] questions. BTW, the particular firearm you place against your shoulder is called a long gun.

@Mazura -- Bows, crossbows, slings, atlatls, drinking straws and a rubber band stretched between finger and thumb also fire projectiles!
